# Electric Potential Difference existence

Tags: electric-fields, potential

How can a Electric Potential Difference be established within a conducting surface?
Many sources suggest that there is always an electric field present when a potential difference exists, but is not because of the electric field that the electrons move to one side of the conducting surface which causes the potential difference, and the result of this potential difference is that the electrons move back to the lower potential?

Comment: could you word your question better ?

Comment: Not so clear what you are asking. It is because of the electric fields that electrons will move and hence you can't establish a lasting potential difference over a conducting surface.

Comment: In some of the high school textbooks it is indicated that  a potential difference creates an electric field, which moves the electrons, obviously this order of precedence cannot be correct, so i wanted to know what exactly leads to what.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your question is like the question "which came first, the chicken or the egg?"

Electric field and potential are linked via the equation:  the electric field is equal to minus the potential gradient.

They are two different ways at looking at the same things.  The electric field in terms of forces and the potential in terms of energy.

When there is a potential difference across a conductor there must also be an electric field inside the conductor and so the mobile charge carriers within the conductor will move.
You can say the the mobile charge carriers move because of the force on them due to the electric field inside the conductor or you can say that mobile charge carriers move to reduce their electric potential (energy).

Comment: Yes, it is very similar to the chicken, egg scenario. What you said makes complete sense, i was only confused because i never expected science to be left up to belief, i felt that there was a definite answer, however as these are natural properties what you say makes perfect sense

Comment: I would add that the electric field is a more general concept. The electric potential, as defined in electrostatics, cannot yield the electric field in some circumstances (when there are time-varying fields). So it is probably more correct to think of the electric fields as existing and pushing the charges, and us describing these in terms of the static potential. Alternatively, you can think of the *more-general* potential (4-vector potential) and the fields as two-views of the same thing, as Farcher explained.

Answer (score 0):

Remember what **potential difference** is:

- On a wire, place 10 charges at a point and 2 charges at another point. If another charge is added, *it has a tendency* to move. Equal-signed charge repels, so it will be repelled the least from the point with only 2 charges - naturally it will move there and this is what we define as potential difference. If will always move towards the lowest potential, because the electric repulsion force is lowest from here.

Now think about what **electric field** is:

- Charge is either repelled or attracted by other charge. Of you have 10 charges, they collectively repel harder (with a larger force) on another charge, than if you only had two. The *force per charge* at a point is what we call electric field: $E=F/q$.

And now tell me, if you see a difference between the two phrases **potential difference** and **electric field** or if they merely are two ways of describing the same phenomena.

A potential difference does not "cause" the electric field. But the electric field - which is the fact, that charges interact - might though be called the cause for the potential difference.